# How do i configure a simple dante instance?

Tags: proxy, configuration, authentication, socks, dante

I'm trying to set up a simple SOCKS proxy on Amazon EC2, but I'm not able to figure out the documentation and configuration file for dante. For now i've been able to set up a proxy without authentication (which i took offline immediately after verifying that it worked).

What i want to achieve is a single user proxy for myself with simple plaintext login. I assume i should use the username method in danted.conf but no matter what i try i cant figure it out.

Here is the current config without any authentication since i cant get it to work.

```
logoutput: /var/log/danted
internal: eth0 port = 1080
external: eth0
method: username none

user.privileged: root
user.notprivileged: nobody
user.libwrap: nobody
client pass {
    from: 0.0.0.0/0 port 1-65535 to: 0.0.0.0/0
}

pass {
     from:  0.0.0.0/0 to: 0.0.0.0/0
     protocol: tcp udp
}
```

Comment: http://serverfault.com/a/336113/59925

Comment: Post your comment as an answer and ill accept it. Dont know how i missed that one, thanks.

Comment: I don't want to dupplicate my post, you can upvote it in that topic.